# How to attach an AWS EFS volume to an EC2 spot instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I have successfully attached an EFS volume to an EC2 instance, but I need to know how to attach the EFS volume to an EC2 **spot** instance.

Comment: Although I have never attached EFS to a spot instance but I would imagine it would work the same way. Don't we get the option to attach efs volume when the instance is a spot instance?

Comment: Just mount the EFS volume as normal. The command would be run on the instance itself, since it's an Operating System activity. See: [Mounting EFS file systems - Amazon Elastic File System](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you start to create a non spot-instance and mark the checkboxes for attaching an efs-filesystem, this results in an autogenerated script filled into the user-data-field.

Copy this script and cancel the non-spot-instance creation.

Start to create a spot instance and just paste the script in the user-data-field you get in the create-spot-request-instance-mask.
I tried it with ubuntu-linux 20.04 and it works perfect!

Script for example looks like this (if you use another os/distribution/version it may differ):

```
#cloud-config
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
runcmd:
- yum install -y amazon-efs-utils
- apt-get -y install amazon-efs-utils
- yum install -y nfs-utils
- apt-get -y install nfs-common
- file_system_id_1=my-filessystem-id
- efs_mount_point_1=/mnt/efs/fs1
- mkdir -p "${efs_mount_point_1}"
- test -f "/sbin/mount.efs" && printf "\n${file_system_id_1}:/ ${efs_mount_point_1} efs tls,_netdev\n" >> /etc/fstab || printf "\n${file_system_id_1}.efs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:/ ${efs_mount_point_1} nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport,_netdev 0 0\n" >> /etc/fstab
- test -f "/sbin/mount.efs" && grep -ozP 'client-info]\nsource' '/etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.conf'; if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then printf "\n[client-info]\nsource=liw\n" >> /etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.conf; fi;
- retryCnt=15; waitTime=30; while true; do mount -a -t efs,nfs4 defaults; if [ $? = 0 ] || [ $retryCnt -lt 1 ]; then echo File system mounted successfully; break; fi; echo File system not available, retrying to mount.; ((retryCnt--)); sleep $waitTime; done;
```